# É possível criar um objeto dinamicamente em JS sem utilizar eval?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, objetos

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
Arr = ["meu", "objeto", "dinamico"];
Val = 100;
Eval = "";
obj = {};
for(i in Arr){
    Eval += "['"+ Arr[i] + "']";
    eval("obj"+Eval+"={}")
}
eval("obj"+Eval+"="+Val);
```

Como vocês podem ver, este código gera dinamicamente a propriedade `obj.meu.objeto.dinamico` e adiciona o valor de `Val` nela, porém esse código é um tanto quanto ridículo, tentei fazer o mesmo código sem utilizar `eval()`, mas não consigo imaginar uma solução decente.

Comment: Recomendo que você use loop for(i=0;...) tradicional ou o método forEach para iterar em vetores. O for-in não garante que os índices sejam acessados em ordem crescente e também pode iterar sobre campos não numéricos (se alguém dizer monkeypatching em Object.prototype ou Array.prototype)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seu código com eval já está usando o truque que você precisa pra não usar mais o eval: Acesso a propriedades via string:

```
//Em Javascript esses dois são equivalentes:
obj.foo = 17
obj['foo'] = 17
```

Já pra fazer o seu objeto dinâmico acho mais fácil construir de "baixo pra cima":

```js
function make_object_path(path, value){
    var curr = value;
    for(var i=path.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
       var o = {};
        o[path[i]] = curr;
        curr = o;
    }
    return curr;
}
    
var obj = make_object_path(["meu", "objeto", "dinamico"], 100);
alert(obj.meu.objeto.dinamico);
```

Answer (score 2):

É bem simples. Um objeto no javascript pode ser utilizado como um array, ou seja:

```
var arr = ["meu", "objeto", "dinamico"];
var val = 100;
var obj = {};
var currentObj = obj;
var lastIndex = arr.length - 1;

for (i in arr) {
    currentObj[arr[i]] =  (i == lastIndex) ? val : {} ;
    currentObj = currentObj[arr[i]];
}

console.log(obj);
```

A condição `i == lastIndex` serve para verificar se está no último índice do array para setar o valor desejado, no caso `100`. A variável `currentObj` serve para podermos modificar o objeto `obj` a partir do último índice criado. Isso é possível pois ao passar um objeto para uma variável o js salva uma referência para o objeto original, ou seja, ao modificarmos o objeto `currentObj` estaremos modificando também o objeto `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

A solução que eu havia encontrado é a seguinte:

```
function createDynamicObject(val, arr, obj){
    //
    if(typeof obj == "undefined")
        obj = {};

    //
    if(arr.length > 1){
        key = arr.shift();
        obj[ key ] = {};
        createDynamicObject(val, arr, obj[ key ]);
    }else{
        key = arr.shift();
        obj[ key ] = val;
    }

    //
    return obj;
} 

//
meuObjeto = createDynamicObject(100, ["minha", "propriedade", "dinamica"]);
console.log(meuObjeto.minha.propriedade.dinamica);
```

mas o que o @hugomg respondeu é bem interessante.